# DJI controller storage tips

Tags: dji, dji-mavic-air-2

I have the DJI air2s, and I have both the RC controller and N1 controller. Obviously I'm going to want to use the RC controller more than the N1. I'm aware that you can take DJI batteries off the charger once they reach 50 to 60% for storage. Does this apply also to the controllers? And what other methods could I use to swap between both controllers?